# Проблема с кодировкой при получении ответа subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x

При написании "пингера" столкнулся с проблемой кодировки при получении ответа:

```
def ping(host: str):
    param = '-n' if platform.system().lower() == 'windows' else '-c'
    command = ['ping', param, '1', host]
    result = subprocess.run(command, timeout=2, capture_output=True, text=True)
    return result
```

И здесь возвращается проблемная кодировка:
`CompletedProcess(args=['ping', '-n', '1', '155.133.248.50'], returncode=0, stdout='\nЋЎ¬Ґ\xad Ї\xa0ЄҐв\xa0¬Ё б 155.133.248.50 Ї® б 32 Ў\xa0©в\xa0¬Ё ¤\xa0\xad\xadле:\nЋвўҐв ®в 155.133.248.50: зЁб«® Ў\xa0©в=32 ўаҐ¬п=44¬б` и тд

Как мне получить ответ в utf-8/eng?

Comment: Из консоли наверное `cp866` кодировка приходит, вроде много раз тут писали, воспользуйтесь поиском

Comment: @CrazyElf, если это так легко было бы найти в поиске, я б не задавал вопрос. Это понятно что из консоли приходит ответ. И первое решение это менять там язык. Может есть питоническое/простое решение?

Comment: Попробуйте `result.stdout.decode('cp866')`